How to install opencv with CUDA support
I need help of building opencv in Ubuntu.
I tried to install opencv in Ubuntu 20.04 - not install libopencv.
I want to install opencv with CUDA support.
I installed CUDA-12.4, CUDNN-9.0.0
Then I tried to build opencv-4.8.0 using this command
test -e 4.8.0.zip || wget https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/refs/tags/4.8.0.zip
test -e opencv-4.8.0 || unzip 4.8.0.zip
test -e opencv_extra_4.8.0.zip || wget -O opencv_extra_4.8.0.zip https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/archive/refs/tags/4.8.0.zip
test -e opencv_contrib-4.8.0 || unzip opencv_extra_4.8.0.zip

cd opencv-4.8.0
mkdir build
cd build

cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
-D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
-D WITH_TBB=ON \
-D ENABLE_FAST_MATH=1 \
-D CUDA_FAST_MATH=1 \
-D WITH_CUBLAS=1 \
-D WITH_CUDA=ON \
-D BUILD_opencv_cudacodec=ON \
-D WITH_CUDNN=ON \
-D OPENCV_DNN_CUDA=ON \
-D WITH_QT=OFF \
-D WITH_OPENGL=ON \
-D BUILD_opencv_apps=OFF \
-D BUILD_opencv_python2=OFF \
-D OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG=ON \
-D OPENCV_PC_FILE_NAME=opencv.pc \
-D OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE=ON \
-D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib-4.8.0/modules \
-D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF \
-D WITH_FFMPEG=ON \
-D CUDNN_INCLUDE_DIR=/usr/local/cuda/include \
-D CUDNN_LIBRARY=/usr/local/cuda/lib64/libcudnn.so \
..

make -j$(nproc)

I ran the 'cmake' command and finished successfully.
But when I run the 'make' command I have the errors.
The error file link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/199fYgRktP9vVPVaI4ISuPefPLdR8wkw9/view?usp=sharing
Does anybody have the same problem before? How to fix the problem.
I followed the instruction of https://github.com/cyrusbehr/YOLOv8-TensorRT-CPP/blob/main/README.md

This appears to be a known issue: CUDA 12.2 fp16 dnn compilation error #23893
